# Is any text-pre-processing recommended for LUIS-bot-app?

Tags: bots, text-classification, azure-language-understanding

Is it recommended to perform the following text-pre-processing tasks for both "training utterances" and "end-user input utterances"?

1. **Replacing with the "root" synonym**. E.g. replacing the words *ordinary/typical* with the "root" synonym *regular*. This is similar to **LUIS Phrase list**, but I can define my own app's internal list, which is not limited to 10 phrase lists.
2. **Stemming**: reducing inflected (or sometimes derived) words to their root form. For instance, the words "connect", "connects", "connected", "connection", "connecting" will be mapped to "connect".

...Am I missed any other text-pre-processing tasks?

Answer (score 0):

With the experiences I have with LUIS am not recommending to do the text pre-processing. LUIS is using a classification methodology using POS tagging. Stemming or replacing the root may change the meaning of the sentence. Best way is to go ahead with the original user created content.

Comment: Did you perform some research on this proving your conclusions? E.g. applying cross-validation techniques to test _with/without pre-processing_ performance. Or maybe you have some links from Microsoft recommended avoiding pre-processing?

Comment: I do have an experience with this kind of a scenario in a chatbot LUIS model. It performed well without pre-processing step.

Comment: In our bot, we applied preprocessing that helped imprvoving the accuracy. However, it has resulted in a over burden of managing the preprocessing and related side effects. Is there any recommendation from Microsoft? Is MS deploying any technique to eliminate need of preprocessing?

Comment: When you pushing the requests to LUIS you can enable bing spell checker. That is enough I think.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Bing spell check is already there. However, if LUIS is trained on "give me mango" then there are poor results for "give me mangos" (plural). Sometimes the confidence is so low even with obvious words that we have to do the preprocssing ourself

Comment: For the words like this I would suggest to use parse lists. Else you can create a simple preprocessing experiment in AzureML Studio and expose as an API.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I conclude that it has to be implemented by user, and it is not taken care by Microsoft LUIS. I am still open for suggestions